# shutil.copyfile makes files that can't be opened? (Python) *SOLVED*

Tags: python, file, directory, shutil

I'm working on a program that deals with files and directories, and my task is to take some files from a list and make duplicates of them, with the extension '.copy' appended at the end. However, when I go into Finder to open these copied files, I get the message that these are "unsupported file types". Could someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

I'm working on a MacBook Pro by the way.

```
def copy_files (c_list = [Path]):
     d_list = []
     for element in c_list:
     shutil.copyfile (element.name, element.name + '.copy')
     return d_list
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that some file explorers handle files on their own accord and don't follow the Operating System native conventions ie: registering file openers by extension instead of mimetype. Since you appended `.copy` to the end of your file names, your exporer may be having an issue. Try removing the .copy extension and opening it again.

If that still doesn't work, assuming you're using the Mac OS native file exporer which knows how to handle files for it's OS properly, please reffer to this warning form the Python3 Documenation:

> **Warning** *Even the higher-level file copying functions (`shutil.copy()`, `shutil.copy2()`) cannot copy all file metadata.*
>   On POSIX platforms, this means that file owner and group are lost as well 
>   as ACLs. ***On Mac OS, the resource fork and other metadata are not used.
>   This means that resources will be lost and file type and creator codes
>   will not be correct.*** On Windows, file owners, ACLs and alternate data
>   streams are not copied.

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Removing the new extension worked! Thank you so much!